# LibreOffice Calc - Are there advanced IF parameters?

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice-calc

Can an IF statement set the value of a variable?
e.g.

`=IF(A1>B1,B1,MyVarb="1")`

I've tried this and got #NAME? as the response of course because LO Calc doesn't know what MyVarb is but I don't know where I could declare it, but even if it was declared somewhere does LO calc support such a thing?

Another advanced feature that would be handy is if the "IF" statement could change the content of a cell that isn't the cell that the IF formula is in,
e.g. In cell B2 I have...

`=IF(A2<A3,"0",A8="foo")`

Content of A2 = 15, content of A3 = 3, so it skips writing the "0" and goes on to produces a FALSE result because It's actually doing a boolean check on A8 rather than writing to A8 which is what I want.

Can these two things be achieved using `IF` statements, if so how?

I can use macro's but using IF statements to achieve this would be super useful and quick.

Comment: You could think of each cell to be a variable in a 100% functional language (IOW, they can't have side effects on other cells), and the workbook to be a DAG of computations. If you want a cell you call "MyVarb" to be 1, then that cell's function should result in that result. If you want A8 to be foo, that cell's function should result in that result.

Comment: Thanks AKS, but I want a test to return a 'result in that cell if the test was true', and if the test was false, then modify a different cell, giving me the ability to have a 'column of truth' and another column of False
That 'different cell' i.e. the 'record of falseness' is to be used as 'storage' which I can process later on e.g.   =IF(storage<>"Too Strong"...

Comment: Sounds like you want `=IF(A1=3,A2,"")` or similar then, to read A2 if A1 is a given value, etc. You still can't have side effects on other cells without macros (ie imperative programming).

Comment: This question is not clear without a complete, specific example. However, I've answered based on the example described in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To set a variable based on your IF statement, just assign a name to the cell that contains the formula. The result value of the statement will be available by that name. E.g., set "MyVarb" as name for the cell containing the IF statement. Now, you can use "MyVarb" in other cells, just like a variable.

Since the IF formula is bound to a cell, you can use other techniques, too, to modify other cells, e.g. by cell reference.

Comment: Thanks tohuwawohu,
but If I understand you right I don't see any difference. Say my "IF" formula is in C3, then what's the point in using C3's 'user given Name' when I can just use C3 in that cell and other cells? (other than being easier to remember/associate of course) 
using my   =IF(A2<A3,"0",A8="foo") example,  Naming A8 as 'MyResult" doesn't allow me to do =IF(A2<A3,"0",MyResult="foo")

Comment: @Micklos: In fact, there's no difference in functionality. In matters of usability, it may be better to use "MyResult" as reference in other cells / sheets than "C3". In general, i also see a problem of usability. If cell C3 can modify A8 directly (without using named ranges, cell references or anything else in A8), it's very hard for other people how the sheet should work. They would have to check the complete sheet for cells modifying A8. Thus, if the value of A8 depends on different cells, this should get obvious simply by inspection A8.

Answer (score 0):

> `=IF(A2<A3,"0",A8="foo")`

That's backward. Instead, put a formula in cell A8 to yield "foo" based on a condition.

> Test to return a 'result in that cell if the test was true', and if the test was false, then modify a different cell, giving me the ability to have a 'column of truth' and another column of False That 'different cell' i.e. the 'record of falseness' is to be used as 'storage' which I can process later on e.g. =IF(storage<>"Too Strong"

If that's what you want, then the solution is simple.

| A | B | C (Truth) | D (Falseness / Storage) | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | =IF(A1>B1;B1) | =IF(C1;"";"Too Strong") | =IF(D1<>"Too Strong";1;2) |

Comment: Thanks Jim (et al) but I was looking for something more efficient than having to have two formula's - one in the cell that containing the formula and then a near replicate in A8.
It would be very useful for my to be able to force output into a different a simple formula.

There are also implications (in my mind anyway) to copying and pasting data. If text 'foo' could appear in A8 with no formula, then macro programming on A8 is much easier (one less rabbit hole to have to go down)